# Java Spring - Execute MySQL Queries from File

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm trying to execute a file containing stored procedures. I use the following code to do so, but I keep getting an error saying that my syntax is wrong. It doesn't seem to like the first line involving the DELIMITER. Anyone have any suggestions?

Java

```
final ResourceDatabasePopulator rdp = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        rdp.addScript(new ClassPathResource("storedProcedures.sql"));
        try {
            rdp.populate(dataSource.getConnection());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Exception

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetEvents`// CREATE PROCEDURE `GetEvents`' at line 1
```

Comment: I voted for this question because I did not know that there is such a thing as ResourceDatabasePopulator in Spring JDBC. Now I do. Thanks!

Comment: Has there been any resolution to this? I am encountering the same problem, the sql is generated from mysqldump so I'd assume it is properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see your mySQL syntax that you wrote to help see the problem. It seems that the compiler is giving you a good hint.  I am more of a SQL server guy myself and I know it can be hard writing embedded or dynamic SQL without the help of a SQL compiler to catch the errors as you go.